# диапазон от начала текста до определённого слова

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Вот, например текст:

```
Welcome to RegExr v2.0 by gskinner.com!
Edit the Expression & Text to see matches. Roll over matches or the expression for details. Undo mistakes with ctrl-z. Save & Share expressions with friends or the Community. A full Reference & Help is available in the Library, or watch the video Tutorial.
Sample text for testing:*
```

Я хочу выделить диапазон от начала текста, включая слово **Welcome** до слова **Sample** . Вот я пишу шаблон:

```
/^.*Sample/ig
```

**i** - регистро-независимый поиск

**g** - глобальный поиск

**^** - начало текста

**.** - любой символ

***** - повтор 0 или бесконечное количество раз

**Sample** - слово, включая само себя, до которого ведется поиск

Теоретически, должен быть выделен диапазон от начала текста, до слова Sample включительно. Ничего не происходит. Что я не так сделал?

Comment: `/(^.*Sample)/ig`  наверное.

Comment: Алексей Шиманский, попробуйте  http://regexr.com/

Comment: а есть какие-то проблемы? что-то ничего не вижу....выделяется как вы и хотите......я еще вот тут пробовал https://regex101.com/

Comment: Перешел по Вашей ссылке. Действительно, там выделяется. А по той, ссылке, что я указал не выделяется.

Comment: так у меня и по вашей выделяется всё :-D

Comment: Отсутствует флаг dotall. Дубликат вопроса.